# wp_register() displays logged in user as site admin

Tags: user-registration

I'm just working on a little hobby word-press site I have;

```
<?php wp_loginout(''); ?>
<?php wp_register( '',''); ?>
```

In the top rite corner of my site, `<?php wp_loginout(''); ?>` works great however `<?php wp_register( '',''); ?>` when logged in always shows logged in user as "Site Admin" is there a universal variable I can use or something to just show the logged in users name.

Note: I am using `('','')` for the `wp_register` parameters so it isn't displayed in  `li` format.

Comment: Answer Here;

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/registerlogin-with-user-name?replies=6

Comment: It isn't saying the user is a 'site admin' aka an admin of the site, it's giving you a link to the admin area aka click here to go to the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Use add_filter in your `functions.php` file to the default text `wp_loginout()` and `wp_register()`.

Copy and past following to your `function.php` file:

1. To change `wp_register()` text:

   ```
   add_filter('register','register_text_change');
   function register_text_change($text) {
       $register_text_before = 'Site Admin';
       $register_text_after = 'Edit&nbsp;Your&nbsp;Profile';

       $text = str_replace($register_text_before, $register_text_after ,$text);

       return $text;
   }
   ```
2. To change `wp_loginout()` text:

   ```
   add_filter('loginout','loginout_text_change');
   function loginout_text_change($text) {
       $login_text_before = 'Log in';
       $login_text_after = 'Sign-In';

       $logout_text_before = 'Log';
       $logout_text_after = 'Logout';

       $text = str_replace($login_text_before, $login_text_after ,$text);
       $text = str_replace($logout_text_before, $logout_text_after ,$text);
       return $text;
   }
   ```

Make sure to provide the correct lables in `$login_text_before`. Note that its case sensitive.

You can change the `$login_text_before` to whatever you would like.